# React Native - Tab Navigator with componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, function, native, mount, tabnavigator

How can I call a componentWillMount method in this class?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    Button
} from 'react-native';
import {TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Friends from './src/Friends'
import Moms from './src/Moms'

const Navigation = TabNavigator({
    Tab1:{
        screen:Friends
    },
    Tab2: {
        screen: Moms
    }
})

export default Navigation;
```

What I am trying to do is call resetAction to reset all the navigation state. However, I do not want to implement it for each tab(Friends and Moms) separately but just call it once in my TabNavigator class( for example in componentWillMount).

P.S. I **do not** want to use redux.

Comment: 1 .use redux for one state of all component

Comment: Any way I can do it without using redux?

Comment: it is too difficult manage state

Answer (score 0):

You can call your reset action before the declaration of your TabNavigator, no need for componentWillMount.

You can check the current routeName, if its within the tab navigator initial route trigger the reset action

Comment: I am kinda confused. How should I declare the reset? Just a method on top of const Navigation? And where am I supposed to call the reset? Since Navigation is a const and I am directly exporting it. There is no class in the file where I can call the reset method. Could you please provide some further guidance? Would really appreciate it!